# Java newbie: Difference between <> and ()?

Tags: java, class

I'm learning Java and had a question about the difference between <> and (), such as when defining a class? For example:

```
public class CounterMap<K, V> implements java.io.Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 11111;

   MapFactory<V, Double> mf;
   Map<K, Counter<V>> counterMap;

   protected Counter<V> ensureCounter(K key) {
       Counter<V> valueCounter = counterMap.get(key);
       if (valueCounter == null) {
           valueCounter = new Counter<V>(mf);
           counterMap.put(key, valueCounter);
       }
       return valueCounter;
   }
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Lesson: Generics (Updated)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: <> and () are never interchangeable, really?  <> is always for generic types; () is always for method arguments.

Comment: As you'll see below, the <> are for something called 'generics'.  You might want to omit <> and what's inside of them for now and focus on the (), which are more important.  The only thing that will be different is that you'll see a warning when you run javac, I think; learn generics later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angle brackets `< >` are used to indicate generic types.  For example, a list that contains Strings is type `List<String>`.  Generics is an intermediate topic which - if you're a beginner - might be a little confusing, without first understanding other Java and programming basics.

Parentheses `( )` are used to invoke and declare methods, and they contain method parameters and arguments.

Your example is using generics to store any type of data in a map without having to be specific about what the type is.  So if I wanted a `CounterMap` that stored key-value pairs of `Long` and `String` types, I could declare and initialize it like so:

`CounterMap<Long, String> myCounterMap = new CounterMap<Long, String>();`

Starting with Java 7, you can use something called the 'diamond' and simplify it to this:

`CounterMap<Long, String> myCounterMap = new CounterMap<>();`

Comment: Thanks Ben! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related.

parameter, variable, argument --

```
void f(Number n)  // define a parameter `n` of type `Number`
{
    // here, `n` is a variable. (JLS jargon: "parameter variable")
}

f(x);        // invoke with argument `x`, which must be a `Number`
```

type-parameter, type-variable, type-argument --

```
<N extends Number> f()   // type-parameter `N` with bound `Number`
{
    // here, `N` is a type-variable.
}

<Integer>f();      //  instantiate with type-argument `Integer`, which is a `Number`
```

my [thoughts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/5w9No6yGcRc) on these terms.